# Traefik cluster fails to find keys in Consul

Tags: consul, traefik, docker-swarm-mode

I've decided to follow [this](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster-docker-consul/) guide and I've encountered many problems.

First of all specifying `traefik` command in `command` was required or else of I've got error that `entrypoint.sh` can't find command `storedata`, and yes `>` yaml syntax is valid way to pass multi-line command in `docker-compose.yml`

So here's a docker-compose.yml:

```
docker-compose.yml
    visualizer:
      image: dockersamples/visualizer:latest
      volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      networks:
        - traefik
        - default
      ports:
        - "8001:8080"
      deploy:
        labels:
          - "traefik.port=8080"
          - "traefik.tags=monitoring"
          - "traefik.docker.network=infra_traefik"
          - "traefik.backend=visualizer"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:visualizer.swarm.xxx.io"
          - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=admin:$$apr1$$dxw2H03E$$VWrfVhKQWyaRiZ4XsfWCK/"
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
        replicas: 1
        placement:
          constraints:
            - node.labels.name == master
    consul:
      image: consul
      command: agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1
      volumes:
        - consul-data:/consul/data
      environment:
        - CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"datacenter":"ams3","server":true}
        - CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0
        - CONSUL_CLIENT_INTERFACE=eth0
      deploy:
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        replicas: 1
        placement:
          constraints:
            - node.role == manager
        restart_policy:
         condition: on-failure
      networks:
        - traefik
    proxy_init:
      image: traefik:1.6.3-alpine
      command: >
         traefik
         storeconfig
         --api
         --entrypoints='Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https'
         --entrypoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS'
         --defaultentrypoints=http,https
         --acme
         --acme.storage="traefik/acme/account"
         --acme.entryPoint=https
         --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http
         --acme.onHostRule=true
         --acme.acmelogging=true
         --acme.onDemand=false
         --acme.email="xxx@gmail.com"
         --docker
         --docker.swarmMode
         --docker.domain=swarm.xxx.io
         --docker.watch
         --consul
         --consul.endpoint=consul:8500
         --consul.prefix=traefik
         --accesslogsfile=/dev/stdout
         --debug
      networks:
         - traefik
      deploy:
         placement:
            constraints:
              - node.role == manager
         restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
      depends_on:
        - consul
    proxy:
      image: traefik:1.6.3-alpine
      depends_on:
        - traefik_init
        - consul
      command: >
        traefik
        --consul
        --consul.watch
        --consul.endpoint=consul:8500
        --consul.prefix=traefik
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      networks:
        - traefik
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
        - 8080:8080
      deploy:
        labels:
          - "traefik.docker.network=infra_traefik"
          - "traefik.port=8080"
          - "traefik.tags=monitoring"
          - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:proxy.swarm.xxx.io"
          - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=admin:$$apr1$$hfqD9TtY$$oGSy9nS."
        mode: global
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
        placement:
          constraints:
            - node.role == manager
        update_config:
          parallelism: 1
          delay: 10s
      volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
networks:
  traefik:
      driver: overlay
volumes:
  portainer-data:
    driver: local
  consul-data:
    driver: local
  traefik-data:
    driver: local
```

And here's what logs shows of `proxy_init` container:

```
infra_proxy_init.1.4rtllualg8od@swarm-manager-0    | 2018/06/12 15:41:35 Storing configuration: 
{
  "LifeCycle": {
    "RequestAcceptGraceTimeout": 0,
    "GraceTimeOut": 10000000000
  },
  "GraceTimeOut": 0,
  "Debug": true,
  "CheckNewVersion": true,
  "SendAnonymousUsage": false,
  "AccessLogsFile": "/dev/stdout",
  "AccessLog": null,
  "TraefikLogsFile": "",
  "TraefikLog": null,
  "Tracing": null,
  "LogLevel": "DEBUG",
  "EntryPoints": {
    "http": {
      "Address": ":80",
      "TLS": null,
      "Redirect": {
        "entryPoint": "https"
      },
      "Auth": null,
      "WhitelistSourceRange": null,
      "WhiteList": null,
      "Compress": false,
      "ProxyProtocol": null,
      "ForwardedHeaders": {
        "Insecure": true,
        "TrustedIPs": null
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "Address": ":443",
      "TLS": {
        "MinVersion": "",
        "CipherSuites": null,
        "Certificates": [],
        "ClientCAFiles": null,
        "ClientCA": {
          "Files": null,
          "Optional": false
        }
      },
      "Redirect": null,
      "Auth": null,
      "WhitelistSourceRange": null,
      "WhiteList": null,
      "Compress": false,
      "ProxyProtocol": null,
      "ForwardedHeaders": {
        "Insecure": true,
        "TrustedIPs": null
      }
    }
  },
  "Cluster": null,
  "Constraints": [],
  "ACME": {
    "Email": "xxx@gmail.com",
    "Domains": null,
    "Storage": "traefik/acme/account",
    "StorageFile": "",
    "OnDemand": false,
    "OnHostRule": true,
    "CAServer": "",
    "EntryPoint": "https",
    "DNSChallenge": null,
    "HTTPChallenge": {
      "EntryPoint": "http"
    },
    "DNSProvider": "",
    "DelayDontCheckDNS": 0,
    "ACMELogging": true,
    "TLSConfig": null
  },
  "DefaultEntryPoints": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "ProvidersThrottleDuration": 2000000000,
  "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 200,
  "IdleTimeout": 0,
  "InsecureSkipVerify": false,
  "RootCAs": null,
  "Retry": null,
  "HealthCheck": {
    "Interval": 30000000000
  },
  "RespondingTimeouts": null,
  "ForwardingTimeouts": null,
  "AllowMinWeightZero": false,
  "Web": null,
  "Docker": {
    "Watch": true,
    "Filename": "",
    "Constraints": null,
    "Trace": false,
    "TemplateVersion": 0,
    "DebugLogGeneratedTemplate": false,
    "Endpoint": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "Domain": "swarm.xxx.io",
    "TLS": null,
    "ExposedByDefault": true,
    "UseBindPortIP": false,
    "SwarmMode": true
  },
  "File": null,
  "Marathon": null,
  "Consul": {
    "Watch": true,
    "Filename": "",
    "Constraints": [],
    "Trace": false,
    "TemplateVersion": 0,
    "DebugLogGeneratedTemplate": false,
    "Endpoint": "consul:8500",
    "Prefix": "traefik",
    "TLS": null,
    "Username": "",
    "Password": ""
  },
  "ConsulCatalog": null,
  "Etcd": null,
  "Zookeeper": null,
  "Boltdb": null,
  "Kubernetes": null,
  "Mesos": null,
  "Eureka": null,
  "ECS": null,
  "Rancher": null,
  "DynamoDB": null,
  "ServiceFabric": null,
  "Rest": null,
  "API": {
    "EntryPoint": "traefik",
    "Dashboard": true,
    "Debug": false,
    "CurrentConfigurations": null,
    "Statistics": null
  },
  "Metrics": null,
  "Ping": null
}
```

Second I've specified everything as in that manual, all the consul prefixes, and so on, and Traefik says that he can't find frontends and backends, also as pretty much anything in `traefik/`:

```
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Transaction 8714f767-ed5a-477f-ae46-6ebd0b4e15c2 begins"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=error msg="Datastore sync error: Object lock value: expected 8714f767-ed5a-477f-ae46-6ebd0b4e15c2, got 068a8a6d-66a9-4d01-b44e-020a601c05da, retrying in 677.561632ms"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..."
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:54:59Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
infra_proxy.0.vzv9q4rns6r7@swarm-manager-0    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Using HTTP Challenge provider."
infra_proxy.0.xu6e4zez242f@swarm-master    | time="2018-06-12T15:55:00Z" level=debug msg="Reset ACME account object."
```

And here's logs from consul container:

```
holms@debian ~> docker --tls service logs -f infra_consul
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | ==> Found address '10.0.2.253' for interface 'eth0', setting bind option...
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | ==> Found address '10.0.2.253' for interface 'eth0', setting client option...
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | BootstrapExpect is set to 1; this is the same as Bootstrap mode.
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | bootstrap = true: do not enable unless necessary
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | ==> Starting Consul agent...
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | ==> Consul agent running!
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |            Version: 'v1.1.0'
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |            Node ID: '05472876-6f66-bb37-5f4d-62b08624a655'
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |          Node name: 'ef0f060252d0'
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |         Datacenter: 'ams3' (Segment: '<all>')
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |             Server: true (Bootstrap: true)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |        Client Addr: [10.0.2.253] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |       Cluster Addr: 10.0.2.253 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |            Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | 
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    | 
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] raft: Initial configuration (index=1): [{Suffrage:Voter ID:05472876-6f66-bb37-5f4d-62b08624a655 Address:10.0.2.253:8300}]
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ef0f060252d0.ams3 10.0.2.253
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ef0f060252d0 10.0.2.253
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 10.0.2.253:8600 (udp)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.253:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state (Leader: "")
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] consul: Adding LAN server ef0f060252d0 (Addr: tcp/10.0.2.253:8300) (DC: ams3)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] consul: Handled member-join event for server "ef0f060252d0.ams3" in area "wan"
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 10.0.2.253:8600 (tcp)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] agent: Started HTTP server on 10.0.2.253:8500 (tcp)
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:19 [INFO] agent: started state syncer
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout from "" reached, starting election
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.253:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state in term 2
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 1
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.253:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: ef0f060252d0
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:25 [INFO] consul: member 'ef0f060252d0' joined, marking health alive
infra_consul.1.uo2dqcm0s6tv@swarm-master    |     2018/06/12 14:38:26 [INFO] agent: Synced node info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command), it must be an array instead of multiline string (`>`).

Note also that with alpine version (and only with alpine version), you need to add `traefik` before `storeconfig`:

```
proxy_init:
  image: traefik:1.6.3-alpine
  command:
     - "traefik"
     - "storeconfig"
     - ...
```

--

Invalid:

```
command: >
    traefik
    --consul
    --consul.watch
    --consul.endpoint=consul:8500
    --consul.prefix=traefik
```

valid:

```
command:
    - "traefik"
    - "--consul"
    - "--consul.watch"
    - "--consul.endpoint=consul:8500"
    - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
```

--

```
visualizer:
  image: dockersamples/visualizer:latest
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  networks:
    - traefik
    - default
  ports:
    - "8001:8080"
  deploy:
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.tags=monitoring"
      - "traefik.docker.network=infra_traefik"
      - "traefik.backend=visualizer"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:visualizer.swarm.xxx.io"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=admin:$$apr1$$dxw2H03E$$VWrfVhKQWyaRiZ4XsfWCK/"
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
    replicas: 1
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.labels.name == master
consul:
  image: consul
  command: agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1
  volumes:
    - consul-data:/consul/data
  environment:
    - CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"datacenter":"ams3","server":true}
    - CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0
    - CONSUL_CLIENT_INTERFACE=eth0
  deploy:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    replicas: 1
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
    restart_policy:
     condition: on-failure
  networks:
    - traefik
proxy_init:
  image: traefik:1.6.3-alpine
  command:
     - "traefik"
     - "storeconfig"
     - "--api"
     - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
     - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
     - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
     - "--acme"
     - "--acme.storage=traefik/acme/account"
     - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
     - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
     - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
     - "--acme.acmelogging=true"
     - "--acme.onDemand=false"
     - "--acme.email=xxx@gmail.com"
     - "--docker"
     - "--docker.swarmMode"
     - "--docker.domain=swarm.xxx.io"
     - "--docker.watch"
     - "--consul"
     - "--consul.endpoint=consul:8500"
     - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
     - "--accesslogsfile=/dev/stdout"
     - "--debug"
  networks:
     - traefik
  deploy:
     placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
     restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  depends_on:
    - consul
proxy:
  image: traefik:1.6.3-alpine
  depends_on:
    - traefik_init
    - consul
  command:
    - "traefik"
    - "--consul"
    - "--consul.watch"
    - "--consul.endpoint=consul:8500"
    - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  networks:
    - traefik
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    - 8080:8080
  deploy:
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=infra_traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.tags=monitoring"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:proxy.swarm.xxx.io"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=admin:$$apr1$$hfqD9TtY$$oGSy9nS."
    mode: global
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
    update_config:
      parallelism: 1
      delay: 10s
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
networks:
  traefik:
    driver: overlay
volumes:
  portainer-data:
    driver: local
  consul-data:
    driver: local
  traefik-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: will you give consul:8500 if consul is running on the host machine instead inside a container ?